# Android notifications not making sound or vibration

Tags: java, android, notifications

```
int icon = R.drawable.icon;  
Context context = getApplicationContext();    
CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";  
CharSequence contentText = "Countdown Complete!";     
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent();
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "is completed!", System.currentTimeMillis());  
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, pendingIntent);
long[] vibrate = {0,100,200,300};
notification.vibrate = vibrate;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; 
notificationManager.notify(myCountDown.getId(), notification);
```

This code in my android application and i get the notification but no sound or vibration.

I've tested on multiple phones all with sound and vibration turned on and up in settings. I've also made sure that i'm asking to use the vibration permission in the android manifest but i still only get the notification...

I've also tried:

```
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
```

and

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

How do I get sound and vibration in my notifications?

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to enable the vibration setting for ringtone and notifications. Go to Settings -> Sound. Check "Sound an vibration".

Comment: This is a common mistake on users... it happened to me

Answer (score 2):

notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
doesn't work ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to put that, but I've tried Notification.DEFAULTS_ALL and VIBRATE and still nothing...

Comment: you did try to create your intent as in docs ?Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Make sure you have the `VIBRATE` permission in the manifest, and that you are running on a device that has a vibration motor.

Step #2: Get rid of `getApplicationContext()`, as you do not need it here.

Step #3: Try specifying an actual ringtone via the `sound` data member on `Notification`, to see if it's a matter of the default not playing (you will need to not have `DEFAULT_SOUND` in `flags`).

Comment: Step #1: Buddy I said in my question "I've also made sure that i'm asking to use the vibration permission in the android manifest"... and I did say phone...

Comment: Step #2: Get rid of it? set it to null? or remove the argument?... neither works... null gives me runtime exception and no arg doesn't compile...

Comment: Step #3: I'm using DEFAULT_SOUND because I want to have it play the default sound... and I should still get vibration though...

Answer (score 0):

```
Notification notif ... //create your notification
```

notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

Don't forget to include the Vibrate permission in your manifest.