# Vibrate after disconnect from bluetooth does not always work

Tags: android, bluetooth, notifications, vibration

I'm trying to make my phone vibrate and display a notification if my tablet disconnects from the phone over Bluetooth. It works if I disconnect my tablet from my phone through my tablet's Bluetooth menu, both when my phone screen is on and when it is off (I've kept my phone asleep for half an hour and then disconnected my tablet from my tablet's Bluetooth menu and it works). It also works if I disconnect my phone from my tablet through my phone's Bluetooth menu. It also works if I walk away from my tablet while holding my phone and keeping my phone screen off.

However, if I walk away from my tablet with my phone screen off, vibration does not occur. The notification does appear, however, as I check my phone after a few minutes and the notification is there with the correct time stamp (so the notification does not just appear when I wake up my phone). I'm completely baffled.

Here's my relevant code:

```
public class BluetoothService extends Service {

public final BroadcastReceiver BluetoothScanner = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String trueAction = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(trueAction)){

            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String deviceName = device.getName();
                dcNotify(deviceName);

                Toast.makeText(context, deviceName + " has disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

};


public void dcNotify(String s) {
    Log.d("status", "commenced");
    int notificationId = 1;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Device Disconnected")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    String contentText = "Disconnected from " + s;

        notificationBuilder.setContentText(contentText);

        long[] pattern = { 0, 100, 500, 100, 500, 100, 500};
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notification.vibrate = pattern;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
}
}
```

Comment: Just curious if you've tried this with a different Android phone? Could it be something about your particular settings that's overriding your application?

Comment: yeah I've tried this with an Oppo Find 7 and Nexus 4 as well (my primary device is a OnePlus One)

Answer (score 0):

> Don't forget to enable the vibration setting for ringtone and
>   notifications. Go to Settings -> Sound. Check "Sound an vibration".

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13905212/972311

Also unrelated but use the builder pattern:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("Device Disconnected")
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .setContentText(contentText)
    .setVibrate(pattern)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
```

Comment: That was actually my initial implementation and it has the exact same problem